# My program doesn't stop when I use fork() several times

Tags: c, ubuntu, fork

I am trying to run the following code on my Ubuntu machine

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  fork();
  fork();
  fork();

  printf("hello\n");

  exit(0);
}
```

When I run above codes with calling fork() two times, I get four "Hello"s as
expected. However, when I run the above code, the program just loops and never
returns.(it does print two "Hello"s, by the way)

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

My thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no loop anywhere and your first sentence contradicts what you write in the parantheses ... what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: I think he's saying that the program, when compiled and run, does not terminate (never exits, never stops); it prints twice before getting stuck in such a state. "Why is this?" is this question. That said, when I compile and run the code, I get the expects 8 "hello"s (and the program terminates).

Comment: Run your program under `strace -f` to trace all the forks.

Comment: Sorry, Felix. What Thanatos said is exactly what I was trying to say

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code a bit by including `pid` to it, just to print what is happening. Take this execute in your system and you'll be able to figure out.

 After three fork "hello" should be printed 8 times (I think by mistake you mentioned two times in your question).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t pid1,pid2,pid3;
  pid1 = fork();
  pid2 = fork();
  pid3 = fork();

  printf("hello in [%u][%u][%u]\n",pid1,pid2,pid3);

  exit(0);
}
```

Out put which I get is as follows:

```
[p@devmach PROG]$ ./a.out
hello in [30092][30093][30094]
[p@devmach PROG]$ hello in [30092][30093][0]
hello in [30092][0][30095]
hello in [0][30096][30097]
hello in [30092][0][0]
hello in [0][30096][0]
hello in [0][0][30098]
hello in [0][0][0]
```